# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type PDO as array

Tags: php, pdo

Here is the error Log

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type PDO as array in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/php/blog/single.php on line 13

Here is 13 number line

```
$post = DB\query('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1', array('id'   =>  $_GET['id']), $conn [0] );
```

i got this error when i try to get post title.

```
<?= $post['title'];?>
```

Full Code

```
<?php 

require 'functions.php';

use blog\DB;
// Connect to the DB
$conn = DB\connect($config);

if( !$conn ) die('Problem Connecting to the DB');

// Fetch all the posts

$post = DB\query('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1', array('id'   =>  $_GET['id']), $conn [0] ); 
// Filter throgh and display in the view
$view_path = 'views/single.view.php';
include 'views/layout.php';
```

Comment: Can you post your DB class? Also, you're not calling class methods correctly.

Comment: change $conn[0] to $conn

Comment: $post = DB\query('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1', array('id'   =>  $_GET['id']), $conn  );

Comment: Now coming this error Notice: Undefined index: title in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/php/blog/views/single.view.php on line 1
<?= $post['title'];?>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$conn[0]`, Try using `$conn`.

For future issues, always remember you can output the datatypes, content, and structures of variables in `php`.

1. Use the following to output the content in human readable format.

   ```
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($variable);
   echo "</pre>";
   die();
   ```
2. Use the following to output the content with datatype and extra info

   ```
   echo "<pre>";
   var_dump($this);
   echo "</pre>";
   die();
   ```
3. Remember functions like `gettype()` etc.

*Also based on your further comments, I'd recommend that you first grab a book or an online course of the language.*

About your next error, remember that in `php` the variable needs to be defined before you can call/use it.

So on the line, where you care calling `$post['title'];` remember to first make sure that that variable **is defined** and **has** the `index` that you intend to call. Also use the above snippets to verify and you should be writing the handling code if that index is not set.

something like..

```
if(isset($post) && !empty($post) && isset($post['title'])) {
....
```

Comment: Thank you all of my friends. now its fixed.